# GridLayout, GridView, RecyclerView... for a 2x8 and 4x8 grid

Tags: android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I want to make two seperate grids, one with 2 columns and 8 rows and another with 4 columns and 8 rows. Which layout should I choose? It only needs to work vertically and there should be some space on the top for a button. I don't want any elements to disappear, but I would also prefer not to scroll to see all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridLayoutManager instead of a LinearLayoutManager when you set the RecyclerView up.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```

Also, this tutorial will provide you further detail https://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-with-gridview-gridlayoutmanager/.